# Handling COM input from Arduino in Java

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to wrap my head around this but it has been too long since I last did something with Java. I'm having my Arduino here connected to my computer. My goal is to handle the values of an optical broken module.

The arduino is sending the value 0 or 1, defined by the status of the module. In Java I used code found on the internet:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class TestClass implements SerialPortEventListener {

SerialPort serialPort;
/** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
"/dev/cu.usbmodem1421", // Linux port, might be different on your PC...
};
/** Buffered input stream from the port */
private InputStream input;

/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

private String alarmCode;

public void initialize() {
CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

// iterate through, looking for the port
while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
    for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
    if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
        portId = currPortId;
        break;
    }
    }
}

if (portId == null) {
    System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
    return;
}

try {
    // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                      TIME_OUT);

    // set port parameters
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                   SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                   SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                   SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

    // open the streams
    input = serialPort.getInputStream();

    // add event listeners
    serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
}
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
if (serialPort != null) {
    serialPort.removeEventListener();
    serialPort.close();
}
}

/**
 * This will be used by R to retrieve the temperature value
 */
public synchronized Float read() {
return Float.valueOf(alarmCode.substring(1)).floatValue();
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and save it to the buffer
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
    try {
    int available = input.available();
    byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
    input.read(chunk, 0, available);

    String s = new String(chunk);
    if(s.contains("1")) {
        alarmCode = "1";
    } else {
        alarmCode = "0";
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}
}
}
```

Now to the problem. The connection is working and in my console I can read out the values. I wanted to create a new class which reads the variable "code" and calls another method once when "code" changes from 0 to 1. But since my programming skills are so low, I'm a bit out of ideas here.

I would appreciate if one of you can help me out!

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

days ago I made an Java class to handle serial port actions like Arduino functions

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.NoSuchPortException;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;


/**
 * Abstraccion del puerto serie
 *
 * @author Enrique Fadanelli Toss
 */
public class Puerto implements SerialPortEventListener {

    private SerialPort serialPort = null;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private OutputStream out;
    private final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private ArrayList<String> datos;
    private String inputLine;

    public Puerto() {
        datos = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    /**
     * Inicia el puerto
     *
     * @param puerto nombre del puerto a abrir
     * @param dataRate velocidad de baudios a usar
     * @return retorna true si se inicio, false en caso contrario
     */
    public boolean begin(String puerto, int dataRate) {
        try {
            CommPortIdentifier id = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(puerto);
            serialPort = (SerialPort) id.open("com", TIMEOUT);
            if (serialPort == null) {
                System.out.println("No se puede x_X");
                return false;
            }
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(dataRate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            return true;
        } catch (TooManyListenersException | NoSuchPortException | PortInUseException | UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Envía una cadena al puerto serial
     *
     * @param data datos a enviar
     */
    public void print(String data) {
        try {
            out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            out.write(data.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void println(String data){
        this.print(data + "\n");
    }

    /**
     * Cierra el puerto
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        try {
            if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                if (br == null) {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
                }

                inputLine = br.readLine();
                //String recibido

                if(! inputLine.equals("")){
                    datos.add(inputLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Datos disponibles
     * @return numero de Strings disponibles en la entrada
     */
    public int available(){
        return datos.size();
    }

    public String read(){
        if (datos.size() > 0){
            String dato = datos.get(0);
            datos.remove(0);
            return dato;
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

There are many missing comments (and possible bugs) in the class but it worked fine for me.

You only need to instance object, and call the methods, i.e.
(I developed using spanish words)

```
Puerto p = new Puerto();
p.begin("COM3", 9600);
while(true) {  // must call on thread or another technique
    if (p.available() > 0) {
        p.read(); // save to a var, or emit an event, etc...
    }
    p.print("string data to arduino"); // can use an echo to debug
}
```

Feel free to take any code parts, and I hope it make easier your logic.